# Warum diese grammatisch komische Konstruktion: "haben fertig"?

Tags: phrase

"Haben fertig" hört man manchmal umgangssprachlich, und zwar öfters betont und mit einem fast scherzhaften Ausdruck. Warum sagt man "Ich habe fertig" oder auch nur "haben fertig"? Ich verstehe die Bedeutung schon, die Grammatik aber nicht. Ist das ursprünglich Kindersprache? Ist das Regional?

Comment: https://youtu.be/yU5bqG9Fx8g um 3:21

Comment: Ich bin erstaunt  ! :) Ist dies der Ursprung?

Comment: @Beta yep. Ein Klassiker. Ebenso wie "Flasche leer" aus der selben Quelle.

Comment: Ganz nachvollziehbar, dass dies ein Klassiker geworden ist. Eure Kommentare sind ja doch gute Antworte Takkat und Stephie

Comment: @Stephie Auch *[Was erlauben ...](http://mobil.stern.de/sport/sportwelt/zornrede-was-erlauben-strunz--3509026.html)* kommt aus dieser Rede.

Comment: Das ist alles ja recht interressant! :) Ich glaubte aber dass es von der Kindersprache käme, und zwar von der Situation wenn das Kind auf dem Klo sitzt und fertig ist. Das wäre dann was es  zur Mutti riefe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eine solche Aussage ist in der Regel eine Anspielung auf die letzten Worte der Pressekonferenz von Giovanni Trapattoni.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Trapattoni#Zitate

Comment: Es handelt sich offenbar um eine wörtliche Übersetzung von Italienisch "Ho finito".

Comment: Willkommen, Louis! Wenn Du *habe fertig*, findest Du vielleicht auch unsere [tour] interessant und möchtest in unserem [help] stöbern.

Comment: [Voller Text der Rede](http://mobil.stern.de/sport/sportwelt/zornrede-was-erlauben-strunz--3509026.html)