# German equivalent to "I rest my case"

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Is there a German equivalent to "I rest my case, your honor". It is something typically said by the defense or prosecution in court when they are ready with questioning a witness.

Comment: it would be helpful if you'd also say what this expressions means in that context.

Comment: Please note that the US American judicial system and rules for court procedures are fundamentally different from German (and other European) ones. Phrases used at court in the USA refer strictly to the procedural rules there, and therefore cannot be applied at court in Germany. The only use-case I see is, as others already noted, a possible translation of dialogues in a movie.

Comment: Can your question also be phrased as: »What do defence lawyers and prosecutors in court procedures say to conclude their pleadings (or other oral contributions) and indicate that they have finished speaking«?

Comment: What use-case are you interested in? Literal use in a court of law or as a figure of speech? The latter will have different, interesting answers.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann the lawyers do not say that to indicate that they have finished speaking, but rather that they are done presenting their case.  The prosecution presents its case first, then the defense.  Once the prosecution rests, it normally cannot subsequently introduce new evidence, though it can cross-examine witnesses called by the defense.  Once the defense rests, there are closing statements and then the verdict.

Comment: @phoog   A German equivalent (regarding the function of the phrase in a procedure) could then be: "Die Beweisaufnahme wird hiermit geschlossen." However, this is a statement that only the judge can make, not one of the parties.

Comment: @phoog Why don't you write your own answer. Apparently you know the formal facts very good and you know, when the phrase is used factual. It seems that the answers are true for german translations of films of American courts - but not so true for the reality.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Lets take a look what "I rest my case" means

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/i-rest-my-case) says:

> said when you believe that something that has just happened or been
>   said proves that you are right or telling the truth ​
>
> also: "my/the case rests" said by lawyers in a law court when they have
>   finished the explanation of their case

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=I%20rest%20my%20case) gives this explanation:

> To say "I rest my case" means therefore that, as far as you are
>   concerned, you've done more than enough to prove your point, and need
>   say no more.

As your question refers to a court room we have to consider what christian wrote in his comment. German and american court rules are very different. Because of that you would translate this sentence differently when used in a german court room or in a movie that takes place in an american court room.

For example: "Your honor" translates to "Euer Ehren" which would be used in a dubbed movie, but a german judge is adressed "Herr/Frau Vorsitzende(r)".

So lets just look at the "I rest my case" part
You have to look at the context, but in (a court scenario) it can be translated with

- Damit schließe ich meine/die Beweisführung ab
- Damit schließe ich mein/das Plädoyer ab
- Keine weiteren Fragen

or more colloquial

- Damit wäre alles/genug gesagt
- Weitere Worte/Fragen sind überflüssig

or very colloquial (don't use in court)

- [Ich habe fertig](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_gefl%C3%BCgelter_Worte/I#Ich_habe_fertig) ;)

Comment: "Ich schließe mein Plädoyer ab" is what you would say if you want to announce that your speech is finished soon. If you want to say that you are finished you would say e.g. "Damit ist mein Plädoyer beendet" or even "Danke für Ihre Aufmerksamkeit".

Comment: @RHa you are right. I will edit it

Comment: I like the inclusion of “Ich habe fertig” but since this is a German learning site you should *definitely* include the caveat that this is not only informal but in fact incorrect German. Ideally explain where it comes from.

Comment: Flasche leer... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCFj9lf8IQE But I agree with @KonradRudolph, this is incorrect German, although very famous

Comment: The dictionary definitions you cite are not appropriate for the courtroom context.  In the courtroom, this phrase denotes a formal conclusion of the phase of the trial in which one side presents its case to the court.  In fact, it's unusual to use the first person singular in a court, because the speaker is usually a lawyer representing another party.  "The prosecution rests" or "the defense rests" would be more usual.

Comment: Nur der Vollständigkeit halber: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39437/warum-diese-grammatisch-komische-konstruktion-haben-fertig

Comment: +1 to "Danke für ihre Aufmerksamkeit" (which can be adding quite some snark -- "thank you for your attention (the conclusions are evident)").

Answer (score 7):

In German versions of American movies or TV serials you can often hear the phrase "Keine weiteren Fragen, Euer Ehren." I would guess that this phrase is used when in the original the lawyer said "I rest my case, your honor".

In a German court a lawyer does not address the judge with "Euer Ehren" but typically with "Herr Vorsitzender"/"Frau Vorsitzende".

Comment: Nach einer kurzen Suche scheint die Phrase aber auch zum Abschluss des Eröffnungsvortrags oder des Plädoyers gebraucht zu werden - im Sinne von "Ich bin fertig."

Comment: Why would the German translators use "Euer Ehren" when it appears (your answer and mtwde's) that this is not really used, and one should use "Vorsitzender" instead?

Comment: In US courts, "no more questions" indicates that one side or the other is done examining a particular witness.  This is different from resting the case, which indicates that the party has no more evidence to present in the trial.  Translating "I rest my case" as "keine weiteren Fragen" would be incorrect.

Comment: @BruceWayne perhaps to retain the elements of difference between the legal systems.  In Dutch, they typically refer to the US Secretary of State as the "minister van buitenlandse zaken" (foreign minister), which always seems horribly wrong to me.

Comment: @phoog - Ohh! They use "Euer Ehren" when translating an *American* courtoom.  Duh, that makes sense.

Comment: @phoog The legal systems are indeed quite different. For example, in a German trial the witnesses are questioned not only by the lawyers but also by the judge.